Generate Swagger client and Server API in same build
In my solution there are two projects. A ASP.NET REST-API with annotations for swagger generation and a Blazor WebAssembly Project. They communicate by an OpenAPI spezification. Target is to generate the swagger.json with dotnet swagger tofile/Swashbuckle first and then build the corresponding WebClient by the result. The following targets are used:
One for the API:
<Target Name="CreateSwaggerJson" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="$(Configuration)=='Debug'">
  <Exec Command="dotnet swagger tofile --output ../HZDLademanagement.Client/Services/OpenAPIS/swagger.json $(OutputPath)$(AssemblyName).dll v1" WorkingDirectory="$(ProjectDir)" />
</Target>

One for the Client:
<Target Name="NSwag" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">   
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OpenApiDocument>Services/OpenAPIs/swagger.json</OpenApiDocument>
        <NSwagConfiguration>Services/OpenAPIs/nswag.json</NSwagConfiguration>
        <GeneratedOutput>Client.g.cs</GeneratedOutput>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="$(NSwagExe) run $(NSwagConfiguration) /variables:OpenApiDocument=$(OpenApiDocument),GeneratedOutput=$(GeneratedOutput),BaseOutputPath=." />
</Target>

Problem is the dotnet comand needs the API.dll for the generation. So it needs to run AfterBuild. The client needs the result of the command for compiling before the build. When building the BeforeBuilds of both projects are executed. Then the build. At last the AfterBuild is executed.
It is not possible to define a dependency between the projects because the API targets net8.0-windows. Windows is needed for Active Directory access. The Client needs to be net8.0 to work with blazor. Currently I build two times so the json is generated in the first one and in the second build client is uptodate. This causes problems if the client needs changes from the server to build.
How to generate the swagger.json by the API and then the client in one build. How change the targets one build after the other?
